# Is there a way to save a spatial join as .sqlite?

Tags: qgis, spatialite, spatial-join

I'm joining data from PostGIS and SpatiaLite databases in QGIS using the "Join attributes by location" (Vector -> Data management Tools) tool. However, this has a big limitation - I can only save the result as SHP files, which truncates my column names because of the 8 character limit. Is there any way to save to a different Format, or can I go another way (maybe a spatial join on the SpatiaLite database)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Processing -> Toolbox -> QGIS geoalgorithms -> Vector general tools -> Join attributes by location` (if you don't see this algorithm, you might need to activate the "advanced interface" option at the bottom of the `Processing Toolbox` dock widget).

This way you can save your results to several formats, including .sqlite.